# How to correctly format date for amazon S3 post upload with joda-time in java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, jodatime

On amazon's [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTFormEncoding) for post uploads to S3 it tells me that I need to format the date for the `expiration` key in the policy document like this:

> The expiration specifies the expiration date of the policy in ISO8601
>   GMT date format.
>       For example, "2007-12-01T12:00:00.000Z" specifies that the policy is not valid after 
>       12:00 GMT on 2007-12-01. Expiration is required in a policy.
>       and I can't seem to figure out how to get joda-time to print print the date in the
>       correct format.

However I can't seem to get it to print in GMT without the -4:00 or whatever for the local time zone.

I tried using the custom formatter with no luck, can anyone give me a hint here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` representations. Check it out:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
System.out.print( formatter.print( new LocalDateTime() ) );
```

will print something like:

```
2012-05-22T12:09:22.988
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyway I can get it to print GMT just without the `+0:00`? that is printing my local time.

Comment: Convert the LocalDateTime to a DateTime using a time-zone of UTC - localDT.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC). Then it will print the 'Z' at the end.

Comment: that doesn't seem to match the documentation examples, they always end with a z, for example `2013-08-01T12:00:00.000Z` and `2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z`, you sure it shouldn't be ```new LocalDateTime().toString() + "Z"``` ?